# Google chart - How to set X-axis interval?

Tags: json, charts, intervals

i've a problem that i cannot solve. i'm using google chart for some charts but i don't understand how to set in X-Axis a datetime interval like: if my datas start with 06:24 it must starts with 06:00 and then 07:00, 08:00 and so.. Actually my gchart works but with an extended datetime.

i post a picture of how is now: http://s17.postimg.org/mwd105r73/now.png

and what i need: http://s7.postimg.org/5nlttfgrf/want.png

That's my code:

```
$matrice = array();
$matrice[]= array ('Datetime','Valore');
//echo json_encode($matrice);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
$val = $row['valore'];
$data = $row['data_'];
$matrice[] = array($data,floatval($val));

}?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);


  function drawChart() {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<?php echo json_encode($matrice);?>
  );



    var options = {
    hAxis: {title: 'Data', titleTextStyle: {bold: true,color: 'black'}, 
            gridlines:{color: 'black'}},

    vAxis: {title: 'Temperatura in [C\u00b0]', titleTextStyle: {bold: true,
    color: 'black'}},
    backgroundColor: { fill:'transparent' },

    title: '<? echo $descrizione;?>',
    curveType: 'function',
    legend: { position: 'none' }
    };


 var chart = new   google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);

  }

</script>
```

Please help me :D thank you everybody!

Comment: This might help you out: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes

Comment: Thank you :D but i've not solved yet :(